# How count the number of lines of a file group?

Tags: regex, linux, ls, wc

I want to count the number of lines that have all the log files in a specified month. So far I get those files with the following command.

```
ls localhost_access_log.[0-9][0-9]-11-11*
```

An example of this file name is **localhost_access_log.10-10-11.log**

**I tried to use**

```
ls localhost_access_log.[0-9][0-9]-11-11* | wc -l
```

this option gives me is the number of files filtered by ls, not what I want. I want the sum of all the lines that have these files. Thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. You don't really need `wc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the total number of lines in all files -

```
wc -l localhost_access_log.[0-9][0-9]-11-11* | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

**Even better -**

```
awk 'END{print NR}' localhost_access_log.[0-9][0-9]-11-11*
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
wc -l localhost_access_log.[0-9][0-9]-11-11*
```